# Is it possible to access VS Codes theme properties programatically? Like, can a person use the VS Code API to change a theme color?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-api

#### Programmatically Accessing VSCode Theme Properties

Is it possible to programmatically & dynamically ***`get`*** & ***`set`*** the colors of *V.S. Code's* theme property's using the **V.S. Code API**?

The snippet bellow demonstrates using The **VSCode API**, and its method, **`getConfiguration()`**, to change settings. I was hopping that something like this snippet would work from programmatically changing theme colors, but to no avail.

```
    const workbenchConfig = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('workspace');
    const themeColor = workbenchConfig.get(`colorTheme.${themeProperty}`);

    console.log(themeColor)

 
    // The argument colorTheme.${someColor} would is obviously replaced with the       
    // theme's property that I want to access.
```

---

*I wanted to access the same object that the `workbench.ColorCustomizations` setting accesses, using the snippet above. My thinking was that I could set the theme colors in the same scope, that is used by `workbench.colorCustomizations` setting, but my attempt was without success.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been a topic for a while. It depends where and how you want to use it. In webviews you can access theme colors as css variables as listed in the [Theme Color reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) and use them in your webview.

In the API you can get some workbench colors, like:

```
const wb_color = new vscode.ThemeColor ( 'activityBar.background' )
```

This is probably of limited use though. You can also get the theme kind (e.g. light, dark, high contrast) of the window with

```
const theme = window.activeColorTheme.kind
```

I am not aware of a proper way to set colors programmatically. Perhaps there are a few hackish solutions under the issue, dealing with this question here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32813

Comment: you can write the color customizations to the `settings.json` and they will be used